# Nontype template argument must be of scalar type error in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, turbo-c++

This:

> Nontype template argument must be of scalar type

is the error that I get when I try to build this program using Turbo C++ 4.5. I have got some errors like:

> non-type template argument refers to function that does not have linkage

But this error is entirely new for me. What is wrong in the code?

```
#include<iostream.h>
template<class T1=int,class T2=int>
class tempex
{
T1 a;
T2 b;
public:
    tempex(T1 x,T2 y)
    {
        a=x;
        b=y;
    }
    void show()
    {
        cout<<"A= \t"<<a<<"\tB=\t"<<b;
    }
};

int main()
{
    tempex <float,int> te1(1.23,123);
    te1.show();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @JerryCoffin There are no non-type template arguments in this code.

Comment: @JerryCoffin but he doesn't in this code ?

Comment: #include <iostream> (without the .h); add std:: before the cout

Comment: @Asaf .. yeah i tried it. result's negative .

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. What compiler are you using? (Edit: I missed the turboc++ tag) I'd say your problem is using a prehistoric compiler. If you switch to a more recent and standards compliant one, the error will go away.

Comment: @user3414734 - After my suggested fixes, ideone says it's working fine: http://ideone.com/6wMFFA

Comment: This is not your real code. This code does not have this problem. _Or_ your compiler is VERY old and buggy (but you didn't tell us what the compiler+version are). The problems that @Asaf are tangential and unrelated to your error messages (though you should follow his advice in order to write compliant C++ code, because yours is from pre-1998).

Comment: @user3414734 it seems that your compiler does not support default arguments for class templates. try to remove default template arguments and compile the code anew.

Comment: @Praetorian . Turbo C++ 4.5 .

Comment: @quantdev: Sorry--I misread his question as: "What does this error message mean?" instead of: "Why does my ancient compiler fail?"

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `older-than-you-are` has me rotfling.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You seem to be using an **ancient compiler**. Try it with one of the modern, free ones, for example VC++ 2013 Express Edition. You will get a more appropriate error message:

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'iostream.h' :
    No such file or directory
```

When you fix this by changing `<iostream.h>` to `<iostream>`, you will get:

```
error C2065: 'cout' : undeclared identifier
```

And if you fix this, too, by changing `cout` to `std::cout`, the code will compile with just one warning:

```
warning C4305: 'argument' : truncation from 'double' to 'float'
```

This is fixed by changing `1.23` to `1.23f`.

Here we go. A complete, modern C++ program.

Answer (score 10):

Turbo C++ 4.5 is from 1994!!! C++ wasn't even standardised until 1998. It is little surprise, then, that your antiquated software cannot parse this [almost] valid C++ program.

What else happened in 1994? Hmm, let's see:

- The Western Hemisphere is declared free of polio;
- Netscape Communications creates HTTP Secure for its Netscape Navigator web browser;
- Sony releases the first Playstation;
- U.S. President Bill Clinton delivers his first State of the Union address;
- Apple Computer, Inc. releases the first Macintosh computers to use the new PowerPC Microprocessors (this is considered to be a major leap in personal computing);
- Nelson Mandela is inaugurated as South Africa's first black president;
- Sega releases Sonic 3 for the Mega Drive;
- Mrs. Doubtfire available on home video (VHS).

You really ought to use something from this century, like GCC 4.9, or Microsoft Visual Studio 2013; you could have used an "old" compiler like GCC 4.1 or Visual Studio 2005, and it would still be a *decade* younger than the dinosaur you've dredged up. Where did you even find it?!

Comment: Yes.The mistake is mine. i should have tried the new compilers.

Comment: +1 for bothering to post the actual year in which Turbo C++ 4.5 was released.

Comment: "...something from this *millennium*" sounds more impressive.

Comment: @Constructor: Excessive hyperbole ruins the point. It's also an over-used trope.